# Response time of sequential probability ratio test for continuous-time observation process?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, decision-theory

I hope to simulate the response time of a binary decision problem given continuous-time observation using sequential probability ratio test (SPRT). Traditionally with discrete-time SPRT, we calculate the sum of log-likelihood ratio of all the samples, and compare it with a threshold.

But when simulating a continuous-time process numerically, we still need to discrete the time, yet the time interval we choose directly determine the number of samples we get per second, and if we still use discrete-time version of SPRT, the decision time should depend on the simulation sampling rate, which I don't think is reasonable.

I hope to know what would be a proper theoretical formulation of continuous-time SPRT?

Comment: Could you describe what "continuously in time" data would look like?  Such an animal seems impossible, because no dataset could contain the uncountable infinity of values implied by "continuous."

Comment: @wuber Like a system that directly operates on continuous-time analog signal, I guess? Although I don't know what exactly it looks like, but I have a vague feeling that there should be at least a theoretical description of this kind of decision problem, and the result should not be that you can take unlimited number of samples in an infinitely short amount of time and generate the proper decision.

Comment: Exactly--and (assuming you sample the signal at regular intervals)--doesn't that put you right back into the classical setting of a stream of data?  Could you characterize how you think your situation differs from the other information you have researched about the SPRT?

Comment: @wuber Here is the difference. If you simulate a dynamic system given the differential equations numerically, the result should not differ much when you change the simulation $\delta t$, if you have a high enough time resolution. Now I hope to simulate the response time of a decision making process based on continuous-time observation. If I change the simulation time interval, I change the number of samples/second, and since the discrete-time SPRT calculates the sum of log-likelihood ratio of all samples, I guess that the response time will depend on the sampling rate. Do you get my thoughts?

Comment: @wuber In fact I have already found papers talking directly about SPRT decision making based on continuous-time observation, for example page 8 on this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1801.01574.pdf). But I have a hard time understanding the math about it.

Comment: You have just introduced many important considerations that belong in your post, Cloudy, rather than buried down here in the comments.  It usually helps to articulate the problem you actually face, rather than asking us to answer some abstract version of it--too much detail can get lost in the translation.